# OpenApi - required a bean of type 'org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerIndexTransformer' that could not be found

Tags: spring-webflux, openapi, api-doc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm adding Swagger to my Spring Webflux service with functional controller. First I was getting this error:

> Description:
> The bean 'swaggerWelcome', defined in class path resource
> [org/springdoc/webflux/ui/SwaggerConfig.class], could not be
> registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class
> path resource [org/springdoc/webmvc/ui/SwaggerConfig.class] and
> overriding is disabled.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

So I added spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true to my application.properties file.

And now I'm getting this error:

> Description:
>
> Parameter 1 of method swaggerWebMvcConfigurer in
> org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig required a bean of type
> 'org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerIndexTransformer' that could not be
> found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerIndexTransformer' in your
> configuration.

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company/groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- For all mvc and web functions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Default persistence functions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The application.properties file contains:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Is there a way to avoid this configuration? What is purpose the of the SwaggerIndexTransformer? Because in the website https://springdoc.org/#getting-started they say that "No additional configuration is needed".

Comment: There must be something not disclosed in the question. As you pull in the dependencies the autoconfigurator tried to automatically configure it, but it fails because it says there is already a registered configuration. Are you registering a configuration? If so where is that code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Toerktumlare. I don't have any configuration code. I just have that property in the application.properties file.

Comment: Then i suggest you produce a small roproducible example for others to try out and confirm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error was that in the pom file the only dependency should be **springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui**

Comment: A lot of blogs suggested to add `springdoc-openapi-webflux-core` along with `springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui` as dependency, but it wasn't working. As per your answer, removing the springdoc-openapi-webflux-core fixed the isue.